# Add active class on click for pagination

Tags: javascript

Within my slideshow, I would like to add and remove an active class to each pagination button on click. How can I do this with native JS. My code so far:

```
//Pagination
  var p = document.getElementById('pagination');
  var phtml = '';

  for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    phtml+='<button>' + (i+1) + '</button>';
  }

  p.innerHTML = phtml; // create the pagination buttons

  var pbuttons = p.querySelectorAll('button'); // grab all the buttons

  for(var i = 0; i < pbuttons.length; i++) {
    pbuttons[i].onclick = (function(n) {
    pbuttons[i].classList.toggle('active');

      return function(){
        pauseSlideshow();
        goToSlide(n);
      };

    })(i);
  }
```

Comment: You can toggle a class like this: `element.classList.toggle('className');` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: thanks, scott. But if i modify the code to include classList, it adds active class to all the buttons. How can I add it to just the button that was clicked and remove it for others? (see updated code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Pagination
  var p = document.getElementById('pagination');
  var phtml = '';

  for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    phtml+='<button>' + (i+1) + '</button>';
  }

  p.innerHTML = phtml; // create the pagination buttons

  var pbuttons = p.querySelectorAll('button'); // grab all the buttons
  var activeButton = null; // ref to active button

  for(var i = 0; i < pbuttons.length; i++) {
    pbuttons[i].onclick = (function(n) {

      return function(){
        if(activeButton)
            // delete class from old active button
            activeButton.classList.remove('active');

        // change ref, this is current button
        activeButton = this;
        // add class for new 
        activeButton.classList.add('active');
        pauseSlideshow();
        goToSlide(n);
      };
    })(i);
  }
```

Explanation: 
We have created variable wich stored ref to active pagination button. On click we removed class `active` from old active button and change ref to button wich fired click event, then we add class `active` to updated active button

Comment: try to explain code. otherwise, you may get a bunch of downvotes.

Comment: It's ok. always keep it as a good practise. Otherwise, you will get many downvotes (from experience)